# Remove White background frame in rounded drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment shown on top of another with a transparent background, How can I remove this white space behind the blue drawable?

[image]

this is my Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
      <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
      <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
       <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

and this is the fragment

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="2.2"
tools:context=".ui.main.signup.IdModeFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:background="@color/black_transparent_60"
    android:layout_height="0dp"></LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/id_mode_fragment_round_background"
    android:padding="@dimen/app_padding"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: fragment's background is transparent by default. Maybe its your activity's background that is showing right now which is probably by default.

Comment: The activity shows one fragment and then I add another on top, so I don't think it's the activity and the transparent Linear above the drawable doesn't have a white frame. Maybe I am losing something. Thank you!

Comment: So what color do you expect to that gap anyway?

Comment: maybe transparent instead of white?

Comment: If your 1st fragment has a white background then your second fragment will also show a white background.

What color does your 1st fragment anyway?